# After performing a task the `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange().activate();` doesn't execute in the sheet when I switch to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple function that delete rows in two sheets, *Price* and *Quotation*, that looks like this:

```
function DelRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Price').activate(); 
  sheet.getRange('16:25').activate();
  sheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(sheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), sheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());

  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Quotation').activate(); 
  sheet.getRange('16:25').activate();
  sheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(sheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), sheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  sheet.getRange('D12').activate();   // <== this don't work unless the function stops here**

  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Price').activate(); 
  sheet.getRange('C12').activate();   // <== but this works!**
};
```

I can't get this line `sheet.getRange('D12').activate();` to work in the *Quotation* sheet.

The range that was set by `sheet.getRange('16:25').activate();` remains highlighted in the *Quotation* sheet.

I have tried adding `utilities.sleep()` to pause before switching to the *Price* sheet and rearranging the sequence of the `sheet.getRange().activate();` statements but it all doesn't work.

It only works if the function ends there (i.e. stop at the *Quotation* sheet) and do not switch to the *Price* sheet.

In summary, I just want to set the active cell to **C12** in the *Price* sheet and **D12** in the *Quotation* sheet after deleting the rows in both sheets.

I'd be very appreciative to get some expert advice on what to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

To make the activated cell to "stick", add `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` after every call to `Range.activate()`.

Comment: Thanks doyubleunary for responding and your suggestion. I haven't use it yet but will keep this in mind. I've modified my script to Cooper's suggestion and it works for me. Thanks once again and have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

by

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

The above because `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` returns a active spreadsheet object, to get the active sheet, use `SpreasheetApp.getActiveSheet()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Ruben. As a newbie to app script, I'm still a little confuse when to use these statements: 'SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()', 'SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()', 'SpreadsheetApps.getActive()'. Each seems to have a different set of methods (I hope this is the correct term) - some methods are common across these statements but there are some that are reserved only for a particular statement. I guess I'll have to do more reading to sort this out. But it will be helpful if you can point me to some resources with useful tips to speed up my learning. Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for  you reply Thaddeus. I suggest you start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. Also take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rows has nothing to do with activating

```
function DelRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Price").deleteRows(16,10);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper! Thanks for your suggestion. As you can probably can tell I'm a newbie to app script and Java! It never cease to amaze me how compact the scripts can be! I've tried the statements and it works - the active cell (cursor) remains where they are without needing to reposition them with a '....getRange(),activate;' statement. And my script for deleting rows (actual use) is now just a few clean lines. I look forward to learn to write more efficient app scripts here. Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Following Cooper's suggestion, my previously long script is now just 3 lines like this:

```
function DelRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Price').deleteRows(16,10); 
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Quotation').deleteRows(16,10); 
}
```

It's so much neater and the active range (where the cell pointer is in the respective sheets) remains where it was originally before running the script.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: it doesn't seem to be an answer, the answer was already provided by other user form the community, you can use the comments for providing your feedback about his solution.